# Doxygen : How to avoid text wrapping inside code block

Tags: doxygen, forced-unwrapping

I am writing notes using doxygen. Sometimes I include a code block in it with very long lines

```
\code
    I don't want the next line to wrap
    this is a quite long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long line
\endcode
```

As you can see, the `stack overflow` don't wrap my line and provide a horizon scrolling bar here. However if I generate html using doxygen, the line will get wrapped.

Is there any option in doxyfile or css to make text inside `\code`...`\endcode` not wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

- When you use `\verbatim .. \endverbatim` it won't wrap.
- define your own css file and add this with the configuration option `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` to your doxygen project (see:http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_extra_stylesheet) and have in this file (for FireFox):

```
   div.line {
      white-space: nowrap;
   }
```

on some systems this doesn't work, some good results have also been obtained with:

```
   div.line {
      white-space: pre;
   }
```

Comment: Albert, thank you for the guide. Experiment shows `\verbatim` works. (With one unwanted effect that extra space is added on each line, it simply ignore how many indent `\verbatim` have)

I still don't have luck on setting `div.line`. Actually I already have a css file with some customized setting. Adding `div.line` as you suggested don't work. I am using chrome, not sure if this make a difference.

Comment: Probably has an effect. I also see that when googeling: "chrome white space nowrap bug" there are a number of hits. I don't know the status of these reports though

Comment: change css to `white-space: pre;` and it now works.

Comment: @EricSun thanks for the extension, I'll add it to the answer